# How to stop a Qthread after calling movetothread()?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, thread-safety

When I reimplement the QTcpserver::incomingConnection(), a new QThread and and a new QTcpsocket is created.The accept-fd is passed to the QTcpsocket. Howerver, the warning occurs with the whole process exiting unexpectly:
*QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running*
as the Qthread calls quit() and the two objects is going to be deleted. Here is the code below.

```
 void TcpServer::incomingConnection(qintptr handle)
{
    QThread* tcpThread = new QThread;
    TcpSocket* tcpSocket = new TcpSocket;

    tcpSocket->setSocketDescriptor(handle);
    tcpSocket->moveToThread(tcpThread);

    connect(tcpSocket,&TcpSocket::sigRecvFinish, [=](){
        tcpThread->quit();
        delete tcpSocket;
        delete tcpThread;
    });
    tcpThread->start();
}
```

How can I quit the thread and release the resources properly? Meanwhile, what causes this problem?
I would appreciate if you help me with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Qt has nice asynchronous API so use of threads (in this context) is totally obsolete and waste of resources.

By using lambda in connect statement you have lost thread hopping functionality, which is done by default by `connect`. Result is that you are trying to destroy thread object from thread which this object manages.

Note that [QObject::connect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect) last argument is: `Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection` (connections without lambda). When lambda is used [QObject::connect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-4) do not have such functionality and code is invoked from thread which has invoked signal.

Dropping lambda will ensure that each invoke is done on proper thread.

```cpp
void TcpServer::incomingConnection(qintptr handle)
{
    QThread* tcpThread = new QThread;
    TcpSocket* tcpSocket = new TcpSocket;

    tcpSocket->setSocketDescriptor(handle);
    tcpSocket->moveToThread(tcpThread);

    connect(tcpSocket, &TcpSocket::sigRecvFinish, tcpSocket, &QBject::delteLater);
    connect(tcpSocket, &TcpSocket::sigRecvFinish, tcpThread, &QThread::quit);
    connect( tcpThread, &QThread::finished, tcpThread, &QThread::deleteLater );

    tcpThread->start();
}
```

For technical details see:

[Qt Namespace | Qt Core 5.15.3](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum)

> | Constant | Value | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `Qt::AutoConnection` | `0` | **(Default)** If the receiver [lives in](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread-affinity) the thread that emits the signal, Qt::DirectConnection is used. Otherwise, Qt::QueuedConnection is used. The connection type is determined when the signal is emitted. |

Comment: Thank u for your answer and the code works without warnings. There are still two questions. First, how can I make sure that the Qthread is deleted correctly and the resources are released?  BTW,  why is the 'delete' seems strange?  What is the proper way to destroy an object in Qt-programming？Is QObject::deleteLater is recommended when an object offered by Qt needs to be deleted?

Comment: `deleteLater` is a slot so it can be connected with `Qt::AutoConnection`. This way it doesn't meter from which tread signal is emitted deletion will be performed on thread to which object belongs to. This is the only reason to use `deleteLater` here. I think you should read my answer more carefully and read linked documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace your `connect` with the following code:

```
connect( tcpSocket, &TcpSocket::sigRecvFinish, tcpSocket, &QObject::deleteLater );
connect( tcpSocket, &QObject::destroyed, tcpThread, &QThread::quit );
connect( tcpThread, &QThread::finished, tcpThread, &QThread::deleteLater );
```

Comment: UP: fix removing tcpSocket itself

Comment: this is from original code form OP, yes it is strange, but acceptable.